# How to say "I live at the bottom of a hill"?

Tags: word-choice

I've only ever people say something like 我住在山坡上 but to me 山坡 sounds like the side of a mountain. Google translate gives me 我住在山脚下.

In English we use, I live at the bottom of a hill, not I live at the bottom of a mountain or I live on the side of a mountain; mountain sounds too majestic.

So is 山坡 or 山脚 a good choice for side of a hill or is there a better word to describe where I live?

I want to say something like: Because I live at the bottom of a hill it is hard to ride my bike to work. 因为我住在山脚下，骑自行车上班很难。

Comment: How would you say a 'hill' in Chinese then? Just curious. To me, a hill and a mountain would both be translated into 山 in Chinese.

Comment: For me 我住在山脚下 is OK and natural enough. To sound more colloquial I would say 我住在山边上 `I live beside a hill`.

Comment: A Google search shows that people do say in English "I live at the bottom of a mountain,"  when they want to.

Answer (score 3):

> [山](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E5%B1%B1?prd=so_1_doc), in general, refers to a mountain or a hill.
>
> 坡 refers to a slope.
>
> Therefore, [山坡](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E5%9D%A1?prd=so_1_doc) refers to the side (or slope) of a hill (or mountain).
>
> 脚 refers to the foot.
>
> So, [山脚](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E8%84%9A) refers to the foot of a hill (or mountain).

Depending on what bike you are referring to, it could be a motorcycle (摩托车) or bicycle (自行车).

I think the translation provided by Google is okay:

> Because I live at the bottom of a hill it is hard to ride my bike to
>   work.
>
> 因为我住在山脚下，骑自行车(or 摩托车)上班很难。

If you are staying in a valley, [山谷](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E8%B0%B7?prd=so_1_doc) will be more appropriate.